# Function to get item from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a function for getting an item from a list? e.g. `getitem(list, index)`

Comment: *function*.  I said it twice.

Comment: Thanks JBernardo.  Would you like to add the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe, though the other answers are correct, that he's probably needing to retrieve them using a callable.  To that end, this works:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> get1 = itemgetter(1)
>>> get1([0,1,2,3,4,5])
1
>>> get1('abcdefg')
'b'
```

Comment: I applaude your intuition; that is indeed my use case.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`operator.getitem`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.getitem):

```
import operator
operator.getitem(l, index)
```

Example:

```
>>> operator.getitem([1,2,3], 1)
2
```

Comment: Great answer, but I accepted g.d.d.c's for his/her cognizance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it use this:

```
lVals[index]
```

Or do it yourself:

```
def itemAtPos(lVals, idx): 
    if ifx < len(lVals):
        return lVals[idx]
```